# Using @ngrx/entity for handling collections in store, getSelectors() not working

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I'm trying to implement a NgRx store using @ngrx/entity lib, but I can't retrieve any data by using @ngrx/entity getSelectors. Redux Devtools shows my collection loaded by Effect()'s as entities properly. So my Effect is working properly. Now I want to select the data as array by using the `selectAll` selector from `adapter.getSelectors()` function. My reducer index looks as follows

**reducers/index.ts**

```js
import { ActionReducerMap, createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';

import * as fromModels from './models.reducer';
import { EntityState } from '@ngrx/entity';

export interface State {
  models: fromModels.State;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {
  models: fromModels.reducer
};

export const getModelsState = createFeatureSelector<fromModels.State>('models');
export const { selectAll: getAllModels } = fromModels.adapter.getSelectors(getModelsState);
```

**reducers/models.reducer.ts**

```js
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { createEntityAdapter, EntityState, EntityAdapter } from '@ngrx/entity';

import { ModelsActions, ModelsActionTypes } from '../actions';
import { Model } from '../../models/model';

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<Model> = createEntityAdapter<Model>({
  selectId: model => model.id,
  sortComparer: (modelA, modelB) => modelA.id === modelB.id ? 0 : (modelA.id === modelB.id ? 1 : -1)
});

export interface State extends EntityState<Model> {}
const initialState = adapter.getInitialState();

export function reducer(state = initialState, action: ModelsActions): State {
  switch (action.type) {

    case ModelsActionTypes.LoadSuccess:
      return adapter.addAll(action.payload, state);

    default: return state;
  }
}
```

In my container component I want to select the data by the ngrx/entity selector and display the data using the async pipe. (I reduced the template)

**models.component.ts**

```js
// All other import statements
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromFeature from '../store';

@Component({
  template: `{{models$ | async}} | json`
})
export class ModelsComponent implements OnInit {
  models$: Observable<Model[]>;

  constructor(private store: Store<fromFeature.State>) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.models$ = this.store.select(fromFeature.getAllModels);
    this.store.dispatch(new fromFeature.LoadModels());
  }
}
```

The console prints an error

```
ModelsComponent.html:2
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ids' of undefined
at selectIds (entity.es5.js:45)
at eval (store.es5.js:572)
```

Any suggestions or ideas solving this? Thanks!

**UPDATE [Requested template]**

The template just subscribes to the `models$` observable, same as in the reduces template. The **model-card.component.ts** just gets Input()'s and *ng-content*.

```
<app-model-card
  *ngFor="let model of models$ | async"
  [logo]="model.id"
  [routerLink]="[model.id]">
  {{model.title}}
</app-model-card>
```

**UPDATE [actions requested]**

**actions/models.action.ts**

```js
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Model } from '../../models/model';

export enum ModelsActionTypes {
  Load = '[Models] Load',
  LoadSuccess = '[Models] Load Success',
  LoadFailed = '[Models] Load Failed'
}

export class LoadModels implements Action {
  readonly type = ModelsActionTypes.Load;
}

export class LoadModelsSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = ModelsActionTypes.LoadSuccess;

  constructor(public payload: Model[]) {}
}

export class LoadModelsFailed implements Action {
  readonly type = ModelsActionTypes.LoadFailed;

  constructor(public payload: any) {}
}

export type ModelsActions =
  LoadModels |
  LoadModelsSuccess |
  LoadModelsFailed;
```

**models.effects.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, Effect } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { map, switchMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { ModelsActionTypes, LoadModelsSuccess, LoadModelsFailed } from 
  '../actions';
import { ModelsService } from '../../services/models.service';

@Injectable()
export class ModelsEffects {
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private modelsService: ModelsService
  ) {}

  @Effect()
  loadModels$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(ModelsActionTypes.Load)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        return this.modelsService.getModels().pipe(
          map(models => new LoadModelsSuccess(models)),
          catchError(error => of(new LoadModelsFailed(error)))
        );
      })
    );
}
```

Comment: Please provide the content of ModelsComponent.html.

Comment: @DiabolicWords Updated my question appended template. Can't imagine the error is in the template. The reduced template causes the same error.

Comment: Maybe `this.models$ = this.store.select(fromFeature.getAllModels)` -> `this.models$ = this.store.select(fromFeature.selectAll)`?

Comment: @RichardMatsen Doesn't work, same error.

Comment: I notice `'./models.reducer'` but `reducers/model.reducers.ts` - but that's got to be a typo in the question, right?

Comment: @RichardMatsen importing is correct, *index.ts* and *model.reducer.ts* are in the same folder. *reducerS* is a typo just in here.

Comment: Do you see, by console.log() or so, that models$ in ModelsComponent  gets a value somewhen?

Comment: What is payload in `return adapter.addAll(action.payload, state)`? Should it be `action.payload.models`?

Comment: @DiabolicWords When try to subscribe to models$ in ModelsComponent => Error: "Can't subscribe to undefined" or similar

Comment: @RichardMatsen addAll is working correctly. The redux devtools display the models correctly as **models: { ids: [], entities: {} }**

Comment: Even so, could you please post the actions.

Comment: @RichardMatsen added actions and effects to question. It has to be an error in the selectors, I'm pretty sure about it.

Comment: Cheers, that looks fine (since payload is Model[]).

Comment: What is the type of model.id - I think it should be string or number.

Comment: @RichardMatsen number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh damn, I figured it out. The problem was the `createFeatureSelector`, which just selects features (as its name is saying). I registered the module as `StoreModule.forFeature('configuration', reducers)`

The solution then is getting the ConfigurationState from Feature selector and the models state from default selector.

**reducers/index.ts**

```js
[...]
export const getConfigurationState = createFeatureSelector<ConfigurationState>('configuration');
export const getModelsState = createSelector(
  getConfigurationState,
  (configuration) => configuration.models
);

export const {
  selectIds,
  selectEntities,
  selectAll
} = fromModels.adapter.getSelectors(getModelsState);
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I did this and still I'm getting the same error. Any resolutions?

Comment: Need more information about your problem and your code, this solution works for me. Create a question or stackblitz and let me know.

Comment: I figured it out, there was problem with my state interface due to which it was unable to select the desired state. Thanks.